# Move/fetch cursor in loop (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

I need to create trigger to check if new inserted element's *id* isn't repeated. The problem is in the LOOP statement, console spit out the error:

```
CONTEXT:  SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "foo" near line 7
LINE 1: move forward 1 from  $1
```

Here is my function:

```
create function foo() returns trigger as'
declare xyz cursor for select id from accounts; 
    begin
        LOOP
            if NEW.id = xyz then
                raise notice ''Id is just used!'';
            else
                move forward 1 from xyz;
            end if;
        END LOOP;
    return NEW;
    close xyz;
    end;
' language 'plpgsql';

create trigger foo before insert on accounts for each
row execute procedure foo();
```

Comment: You haven't opened the cursor. Before the `LOOP` do `OPEN xyz`, or use FOR expression instead of loop, like [documentation says](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-FOR-LOOP)

Comment: Adding OPEN xyz doesn't help. I forgot to add I use Postgre SQL 8.1 version (in case it's relevant).

Comment: You don't need that trigger at all. Creating a unique index on the column `id` serves the same purposes, is *way* faster, scales better and is much more reliable.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sure, it is a the best idea

Comment: Indeed but using trigger was imposed in my case.

Comment: I wonder when teachers/professors stop putting out "exercises" like this which make no sense, server no purpose and actually "teach" a really bad way of doing things.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Studies has simply nothing in common with real world scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example has no sense (you can't compare scalar value with cursor). Cursor self is like pointer without any value.

```
  if NEW.id = xyx then
```

Why you don't do

```
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM accounts a WHERE a.id = NEW.id) THEN
    RAISE NOTICE ''Id is used''; -- better RAISE EXCEPTION
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
```

second nonsense

```
  RETURN NEW;
  CLOSE xyz; -- no statement is executed after RETURN
```

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I need, thx! BTW, is it possible to get specific value from the cursor?

Comment: sure, look on FETCH statement, but in this use case is using a cursor really bad idea. You can find a articles on net about "why don't use ISAM style in stored procedures". Joe Celko wrote good books.

Comment: Usually you have to minimize a cycles in stored procedures (databases are not a arrays) - there are lot of examples of wrong using of cursor, cycles, and similar danger things in SQL applications, so be careful! Sometimes it has sense, but not too often.

Comment: Yeah, I'm used to deploy loops because of programming. Thanks for advice, I'll be aware of that!